# django-import-export how to merge/append instead of update for specific fields

Tags: django-import-export

I was able to get access to the new row data and existing instance by overriding import_obj.

```
 def import_obj(self, instance, row, dry_run):
    super(RelationshipResource, self).import_obj(instance, row, dry_run)

    for field in self.get_fields():
        if isinstance(field.widget, widgets.ManyToManyWidget): 
            tags = []
            for tag in instance.tagtag.all():            
                    tags.append(tag.name)                        
            tags.extend(row['tagtag'].split(',')) # concat existing and new tagtag list
            row['tagtag'] = ', '.join(tags) #set as new import value
            # continue to save_m2m
            continue            
        self.import_field(field, instance, row)
```

However, some where else in the import workflow it compares the values. Since the new concat value contains the original value the field is not updated. Import thinks there is no change.

How can i save the instance with the full concat values?